# Airflow : Tasks in a dag with different intervals or have a subdag that running with different frequency than parent dag

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

We are using airflow as workflow manager and scheduler.
**Requiremnet**
1- We have a ETL pipeline in which data is arriving hourly in different file and need to be processed once data is arrived.
2- Data for every hour have a cutt-off limit in which it can get updated and once updated data needs to be reprocessed.

To solve first we can use file sensor with hourly macros to look for file and start processing once data is available.
For the second requirement we were thinking of using some kind of subdag/task which can run with different frequency till the cut-off time and process if there is any update in data.
But in airflow we couldn't find something like that which could run a task/subdag with different frequency.
How can we achieve this ?

Comment: While it won't be the best way (and perhaps error-prone too), **deleting task-instance** of respective tasks will force `Airflow` to trigger those tasks again. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46397373/3679900) and [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/airbnb_airflow/gMY-sc0QVh0). Assuming your tasks are *idempotent*, that would settle-up everything for you

Comment: This will be very error-prone and also I will loose history.I would like to have information about both normal run and late arrival of data.

Comment: Is there any other solution to the problem?